# Where can I find a C library to read Excel and/or ODS files?

Tags: libraries, openoffice-calc, libreoffice

Googling for "ods c library" doesn't lead any useful results.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://gitorious.org/orcus) is only in its experimental status yet, but the idea behind it is to replace the LibreOffice Calc filters by an external Library. The developer is the main LibreOffice Calc developer. The OpenOffice and LibreOffice Calc filter use all UNO and are dependent on the Calc core design.

Answer (score 1):

you could try [libxl](http://www.libxl.com/) although that is C++ (multi platform, but xls/xlsx)

Comment: This is a commercial library. It cost $200 per developer. I was hoping to find something GPL. Certainly LibreOffice has packaged their .ods and .xls readers so that they can be reused?